# method which reads a file and returns a list of countries

Tags: python, list, file-io, casting

i am trying to work on a method which reads a file(containing names of a bunch of countries) and returns a list of these countries.

```
example:(lets say we have a file "file.txt",it contains the following)

    Afghanistan,    647500.0,   25500100
    Albania,    28748.0,    2821977
    Algeria,    2381740.0,  38700000 
    .......(and so on)
    Zimbabwe,   390580.0,   12973808
```

i wrote down a method:

```
def readCountries(filename):
    open_file = open(filename, 'r')
    new_list = []
    contents = open_file.readlines()
    for i in range(len(contents)):
         new_list.append(contents[i].split())
    return new_list    
    open_file.close()
```

this methods returns an output:

```
[['Afghanistan,', '647500.0,', '25500100'], ['Albania,', '28748.0,', '2821977'], .......['Zimbabwe,', '390580.0,', '12973808']]
```

instead i would like it to be something like this:

```
[["Afghanistan",647500.0,25500100],["Albania",28748.0,2821977],...,["Zimbabwe",390580.0,12973808]]
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: cast  the numbers to numbers ;) The file reader does not know, that the comma separated values are numbers, since read from a file, your program thinks, that they are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def readCountries(filename):
    open_file = open(filename, 'r')
    new_list = []
    contents = open_file.readlines()
    for i in range(len(contents)):
         lsSplit = contents[i].split(",")
         new_list.append([lsSplit[0], float(lsSplit[1].strip()), int(lsSplit[2])])
    open_file.close()
    return new_list
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i tried your code but it would give me an error for some reason:
  ~~ ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 647500.0,
any ideas?

Comment: thank you again. i just slightly edited the code. the edited version seems to be working fine.

Comment: Great. Then mark the answer as correct answer and upvote it so that other can get help from it.